# CentOS 7 Network Issue

Tags: centos, ssh, networking, ethernet

Apologies if this has been answered before but I've scoured the internet all day in search of a solution and can't seem to find one.

I have a CentOS 7 server running on VirtualBox which, despite all of the online guide and instructions followed, isn't receiving data and can't access the internet. It seems to be connecting twice, once to a bridge and once to the ethernet. If I run ifconfig, I get this:

```
enp0s3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.2.15  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.2.255
        inet6 fe80::7e1b:b077:eab3:e180  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 08:00:27:83:31:eb  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 266  bytes 57177 (55.8 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1215  bytes 95511 (93.2 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

virbr0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.122.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.122.255
        ether 52:54:00:e8:d1:f6  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

I've followed the guides on editing the connection using nmtui and tried editing the configurations in /network-scripts/ifcfg-enp0s3 to no avail. Has anyone had a similar problem/know of a solution?

Comment: If the issue is on the host/hypervisor rather than the guest, nothing done in the guest will help. As for the bridge in the guest this usually means libvirt is installed (and has little chance to work correctly or fast, considering setting up an "inception" of guest-in-guest might need hardware/bios support on the host and hypervisor settings)

Comment: @A.B I'm not sure that the issue is on the host as the network works fine on the host, it just doesn't work on the VM. I'll look into setting up an "inception" of guest in guest although I feel like installing extra hardware is a little bit overkill. Thank you for you help though.

Comment: forget the guest-in-guest comment. you should concentrate on thinking about how does the host *route* the guest.